# I want to get page heading.in that the name of site will exist?

Tags: php

Hi iam doing sample application i want to have a page heading..like "www.flipkart.com".in that the name of site should exist like "mycart.com".this is my piece of code..

```
<div id=back style="background-color:orange;min-height:125px;min-width:75px;">
<h1 align="center">Products</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want to do. Try to further elaborate it.

Comment: Hi Thanks for response.i want to get have a rectangle div in that "mycart" name should exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Try this code.

```
<div id=back style="background-color:orange;min-height:25px;min-width:100px;height:25px;width:100px;padding-top:5px;text-align:center;">
<span style="font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">My Cart</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to put the HTTP hostname into the `<h1>` tag?  Lots of useful information about the PHP and server environment is available in [the `$_SERVER` superglobal array](https://www.php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php).

```
<h1><?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?> - Products</h1>
```

Note that you should be using CSS rules to align the H1.

```
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```